# SOQL WHERE + Integer on Auto Number

Tags: apex, soql, where

I want to retrieve the first x records in my dataset. Logically, I created an Auto Number field, but it's acting like a string. Example:

```
[SELECT id__c FROM Person__c WHERE id__c < '4']
```

incorrectly returns:

```
{1, 10, 2}
```

expecting

```
{1, 2, 3}
```

I have made a squirrelly work-around using IN ('1', '2', ..., x) and use a for-loop to build the list. Is there a best practice or at cleaner method?

(Note: Tried ORDER BY + LIMIT x, but ordering is obeying string sorting rules. Considering adding a trigger to convert the AutoNumber to an int or manage my own auto number as Integer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auto-number fields are strings, as they can contain letters, too. To make things easier, consider changing the "Display" to something like `0000000000`, which will generate numbers like `0000000001`, `0000000002`, `0000000003`, etc. You can use between one and ten `0`s, so choose whichever you think will be most appropriate. Otherwise, if you do need them to be numbers, you could indeed do this in a trigger or even a flow. Or, as a more direct route, you can probably just `ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC` to get the first of the created records. This is also convenient because date fields are also indexed.